# Get output from datePicker?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, datepicker

I have a datepicker on my site - In the head i include a load of js files and then in the body all that is needed is to write :

```
<form class="form-horizontal row-border" action="#">
<div class="form-group">                            
<div class="inlinepicker datepicker-liquid"></div>
</form>
```

When the page is loaded, the DatePicker renders and is interactive and you can select a date, i just have absolutely no idea how to get an output from it? Im used to `<input name='abc'>` in order to get outputs from forms and pass to php files etc.

What i need to do, is to get the output from the form and pass through to a php file which will do a few things with it.

Could someone please offer any advice? D:. Thanks.

Comment: you probably need ajax ..http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks but i'm familiar with ajax - what im stuck on is What im going to be posting to the script via the ajax request.

Comment: so are you trying to get the date value..???

Answer (score 0):

[datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
<body>
Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
</body>
```

from the id of input tag like `$("#datepicker").val();`, you can get the value.

Comment: There is not an input tag. I have a current framework for a DatePicker that i would like to use. im aware of the simple datePicker jQuery API but i don't want to use that. I dont want my user to have to click a textbox to prompt a popup calendar. I have a calendar onscreen which the user can select from.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the submit button click or form submit, get the datepicker value in it and put it in a hidden field.

```
<form class="form-horizontal row-border" action="#">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="inlinepicker datepicker-liquid">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="datePickerValue" id="hdnDatePickerValue" />
    <input type="button" onclick="onSubmit()" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script>
    function onSubmit() {
        $("#hdnDatePickerValue").val($("#datepicker").val());
    }
</script>
```